# React useRef is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I think I may be misusing `useRef` here. When I try to draw to the canvas I am getting the following error: `cannot set 'fillStyle' of undefined`.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import useWindowSize from "../hooks/useWindowSize";

export default function Player() {
  const canvasRef = useRef();
  const ctx = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    ctx.current = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
  }, []);
  ctx.current.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.current.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Hello</div>
      <canvas ref={canvasRef} width="500" height="500" />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: what is ctx? your using useRef but never assigning that ref to anything?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment I think I assign cnvRef.current.getContext(‘2d’) to ctx.current in useEffect function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first time you are trying to access `ctx.current`, it's still undefined because the assignment inside this effect still didn't happen:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    ctx.current = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d')
},[])
```

This is because the effect is run **after** the rendering phase.

You need to do that inside `useEffect` instead:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    ctx.current = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d')
    ctx.current.fillStyle= "green"
    ctx.current.fillRect(20,20,150,100)
},[])
```

Comment: @James, I updated my answer to better explain what's happening, I guess the mistake you were making is thinking that the `effect` run before the render phase.