# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getContext')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, canvas, gsap

I'm attempting to make a scrolling animation with GSAP however, I can't seem to get useRef to work the way I like.

I'm trying to make canvasRef equal to the canvas in the HTML however I'm getting the error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getContext')

and when I console log canvasRef I get back {current: undefined, width: 1281, height: 800}

any advice help would be great, thanks

```
function Landing() {
  const canvasRef = useRef();
  canvasRef.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvasRef.height = window.innerHeight;

  console.log(canvasRef);

  const context = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
  const frameCount = 230;

  const currentFrame = (index) =>
    `../../assets/landing-animations/${(index + 1).toString()}.jpg`;
  const images = [];
  let ball = { frame: 0 };

  for (let i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = currentFrame(i);
    images.push(img);
  }

  function render() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasRef.width, canvasRef.height);
    context.drawImage(images[ball.frame]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="landing">
      <h1 className="landing__header">Welcome to my portfolio</h1>
      <canvas className="landing__canvas" ref={canvasRef}></canvas>;
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React useRef is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58494691/react-useref-is-undefined)

Comment: I attempted that but unfortunately it still didn't work

Comment: CanvasRef only contains a reference after the canvas is rendered.  You are attempting to use it before the canvas exists.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running before the elements are rendered.

Plop all of your code inside of a `useEffect` and it should fix your issue.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    // ... your code (except the return and definitions)
}, []);
```

The array needs to be empty (but still there) so React knows to only run it once.
That function will run once `onMount`. ([React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html))

Make sure you leave your `useRef`s and other definitions outside of the `useEffect` so you can access the ref from your code.

```js
function Landing() {
  const canvasRef = useRef();
  canvasRef.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvasRef.height = window.innerHeight;

  console.log(canvasRef);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (canvasRef.current == null) return;

    const context = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
    const frameCount = 230;

    const currentFrame = (index) =>
      `../../assets/landing-animations/${(index + 1).toString()}.jpg`;
    const images = [];
    let ball = { frame: 0 };

    for (let i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
    const img = new Image();
      img.src = currentFrame(i);
      images.push(img);
    }

    function render() {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasRef.width, canvasRef.height);
      context.drawImage(images[ball.frame]);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="landing">
      <h1 className="landing__header">Welcome to my portfolio</h1>
      <canvas className="landing__canvas" ref={canvasRef}></canvas>;
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks, I done that but now canvasRef is undefined with every first render

Comment: React likes to render twice in dev mode if you have strict mode enabled. Just add an `if (canvasRef.current == null) return;` to the top of the `useEffect()`